# How to change topic names and schema names along with namespaces to format topicPrefix.tableName in debezium

Tags: sql-server, debezium, change-data-capture, spark-avro, debezium-connect

I am using debezium 2.0.0 and by default it creates topic names and avro schemas for cdc events in format `<server>.<database>.<db owner>.tableName-value`

I have used a custom transform to change topic names to `<topic.prefix>.tableName`
Plugin: [Link](https://jcustenborder.github.io/kafka-connect-documentation/projects/kafka-connect-transform-common/transformations/ChangeTopicCase.html)

It creates topics and generates schemas fine with `<topic.prefix>.tableName`

**Issue**: In avro schema generated by debezium, namespaces and connect.name still have values with prefix `<server>.<database>.<db owner>`

How to change all the references of `<server>.<database>.<db owner>` in the schema value and key. Is there any configuration for the same in latest versions of debezium?

For example
Topic.prefix=dev

```
Topic name after transform: dev.mytable
Schema name: dev.mytable

In schema,
"namespace": "dev.mydatabase.dbo.mytable"
"connect.name": "dev.mydatabase.dbo.mytable.Value"
```